# Setting up a proxy pass for rest api server not working

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, cloudflare, ubuntu-20.04

So I am trying to setup proxy pass to a rest api that is on port 30422, basically what I want to do is have for example sub-domain.example.com link to the port 30422 on the same webhost. I am hosting the webserver on nginx, and have linked a domain already.

What I have tried was adding my new sub-domain on cloudflare (I use cloudflare as protection) And then also making my new subdomain file in the sites-available folder and symlinking it to sites-enabled folder.

This was my first attempt, which didn't work:

```
server {
    listen 80;  # Port on which Nginx will listen for incoming requests
    server_name sub-domain.example.com;  # Your domain name or server IP

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com:30422;  # Address of your REST API server
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Then I tried to use curl on the vps itself on the subdomain, that didn't work. Then I tried to ping the actual vps ip with the port 30422 and that returned the wanted response from the rest api, that is hosted on the same vps.

So instead I updated my nginx config to instead go thru the vps ip and the port as proxy pass:

```
server {
    listen 80;  # Port on which Nginx will listen for incoming requests
    server_name sub-domain.example.com;  # Your domain name or server IP

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:30422;  # Address of your REST API server
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Which in turn didn't work either.

I also tried this configuration, but to no avail.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub-domain.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:30422;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

This is my first attempt at doing this, and I am just trying to learn. I have looked for answers but none of the solutions I tried worked.

Edit: I even tried disabling always https for cloudflare, and then going back to using proxy_set_header. Still doesn't work.

This is the output I get when using curl with verbose output (sub-domain.example.com)

```
*   Trying 104.21.93.82:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to sub-domain.example.com (104.21.93.82) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: sub-domain.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 12 Jun 2023 20:40:35 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
< Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=bO266eNsXPsKOXRa3nqoNi3wRJPkkYH8a35%2Bvcaq%2B43iQtBIqIk0Lgbf0R8%2BOpCtE6Xc1jYWskuZo6f4XWKa9GRpcCzP5E9NdC6F6kSs9HFLca2uuctXESwAdq%2BO%2FWT9t1EAyuB%2FhRmdGu%2BdWA%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
< NEL: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
< Server: cloudflare
< CF-RAY: 7d64e8e85b75414c-LHR
< alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400
<
* Connection #0 to host sub-domain.example.com left intact
```

Edit 2, requested by @HBruijn

sudo netstat -tnlp & sudo ss -tnlp

```
[1] 48297
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29439/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      660/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1377/sshd: /usr/sbi
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29439/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      29439/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::30422                :::*                    LISTEN      13143/node
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1377/sshd: /usr/sbi
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      29439/nginx: master
State      Recv-Q     Send-Q           Local Address:Port            Peer Address:Port     Process
LISTEN     0          511                    0.0.0.0:80                   0.0.0.0:*         users:(("nginx",pid=29441,fd=6),("nginx",pid=29440,fd=6),("nginx",pid=29439,fd=6))
LISTEN     0          4096             127.0.0.53%lo:53                   0.0.0.0:*         users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=660,fd=13))
LISTEN     0          128                    0.0.0.0:22                   0.0.0.0:*         users:(("sshd",pid=1377,fd=3))
LISTEN     0          511                    0.0.0.0:443                  0.0.0.0:*         users:(("nginx",pid=29441,fd=8),("nginx",pid=29440,fd=8),("nginx",pid=29439,fd=8))
LISTEN     0          511                       [::]:80                      [::]:*         users:(("nginx",pid=29441,fd=7),("nginx",pid=29440,fd=7),("nginx",pid=29439,fd=7))
LISTEN     0          511                          *:30422                      *:*         users:(("node",pid=13143,fd=19))
LISTEN     0          128                       [::]:22                      [::]:*         users:(("sshd",pid=1377,fd=4))
LISTEN     0          511                       [::]:443                     [::]:*         users:(("nginx",pid=29441,fd=9),("nginx",pid=29440,fd=9),("nginx",pid=29439,fd=9))
```

And when using curl -vv on localhost and the vps's ip

```
curl -vv http://localhost:30422
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:30422...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 30422 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:30422
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 24
< ETag: W/"18-XPDV80vbMk4yY1/PADG4jYM4rSI"
< Date: Tue, 13 Jun 2023 18:37:24 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"error":"Unauthorized"}
```

```
curl -vv http://81.xx.xxx.xx:30422
*   Trying 81.xx.xxx.xx:30422...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 81.16.176.39 (81.xx.xxx.xx) port 30422 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 81.xx.xxx.xx:30422
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 24
< ETag: W/"18-XPDV80vbMk4yY1/PADG4jYM4rSI"
< Date: Tue, 13 Jun 2023 18:38:20 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
<
* Connection #0 to host 81.xx.xxx.xx left intact
{"error":"Unauthorized"}
```

Comment: When `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:30422` fails it suggests that your API is NOT running on port 30422 of the same system as where you run nginx. -  Check if your API is actually  up and running , confirm the correct port (use for example `sudo netstat -tnlp` & `sudo ss -tnlp` ; test if it responds to HTTP requests with `curl -vv http://hostname:30422`  and or curl -vv http://localhost:30422`)   .

Comment: @HBruijn It is running, I have it running in a screen instance. The thing is the api is 100% running cause If I try to use the VPS ip and the port with curl it returns the wanted response. Same if I do localhost and the port, aswell as 127.0.0.1 and the port works as wanted as well. The only thing that doesn't work rn is using the subdomain sub-domain.example.com

Comment: I also edited the post and added the curl -vv results aswell as the sudo netstat results.